# Why doesn't SpaceX land boosters in Africa?

Tags: spacex, rockets, falcon-9, falcon-heavy, recovery

Apart from the obvious answer that it'd take too long to get the booster back across the Atlantic, why doesn't SpaceX leave the main or centre booster in space a little bit longer and guide it to land on dry land rather than on a small pitching barge in the middle of the ocean?

It wouldn't help in cases where there's damage to the booster, but I would have thought that it was an easier target.

Would the booster be traveling too fast to slow down safely?

Comment: "*but I would have thought that it was an easier target.*"  Sure, because Africa Is Big, and Boats Are Tiny, but... **you don't just land in Africa**; you land **on one specific landing pad**.

Comment: @RonJohn - but with a pad on land you can make it bigger than a barge and therefore have a larger margin of error - at least for the position.

Comment: Chasing an unnecessary goal though - there's no signs that the size of the pad are limiting factors on landing, and existing land pads are't significantly larger nor do the rockets land further from center on land. No indication a larger pad would help.

Comment: Where in Africa?

Comment: @Quora I am perfectly aware that there are unstable counties on Africa (as there are all over the world) but not all countries on Africa are like that. Also Somalia and Sudan are in East Africa and rule themselves out on geography not politics.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The boosters do not have the range to get to Africa because they aren't going fast enough. If you look at the graphic below it shows a Falcon Heavy mission. The side boosters do not get very far downrange at all so they return to the cape. The drone ship for the core booster was located 1236km downrange, Africa is over 6000km downrange.

[image]

The graphic came from [this site](https://www.elonx.net/launch-and-landing-profiles/), which has many other profiles.

Comment: This is only half the reason. The other half is probably that Elon Musk just really wanted to land a rocket on a boat.

Comment: If he ever names a barge "Grey Area" I'll be seriously worried.

Comment: @GdD whoosh (on my part) - please explain. Thanks.

Comment: @KlaymenDK, SpaceX barges are named after self-aware, hyper-intelligent ships from Iain M Banks culture sci-fi novels. "Of Course I Still Love You" and "Just Read The Instructions" are 2 of them. "Grey Area" is one that has no qualms about invading human minds and collects implements of torture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCU_Grey_Area .

Comment: @GcD: Fortunately he's still got [plenty of other names to choose from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spacecraft_in_the_Culture_series). Although some of them (like "Death And Gravity", "Funny, It Worked Last Time..." or "Only Slightly Bent") might have unwelcome associations in context. (I did use some of them for [a KSP mission I flew a while ago](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/168900-falcon-heavy-to-duna/&do=findComment&comment=3263501), though.)

Comment: @dotancohen afaik, no first stage has ever made it halfway to africa. Even the saturn V second stage fell well short of africa. I doubt cost had much to do with it, except in the sense that SSTO is too expensive to be worthwhile..

Comment: @dotancohen if you can make it to Africa you can make it to orbit, which means you could do an RTLS the long way around, obviating the need for a landing in Africa.

Answer (score 24):

In addition to the other answers, a fixed site in Africa would limit the available launch inclinations to a narrow band. A ship can be positioned anywhere in the ocean.

Comment: This is probably not so relevant. A small course correction after 2nd stage separation would shift the landing point north by hundreds of kilometers.

Comment: This point is very relevant because it goes right along with the lack of fuel to even get to Africa - it would take yet more fuel to shift your ballistic touchdown point. This is another aspect to the 'lack of fuel, lack of flexibility to deal with fuel constraints.'

Comment: They already use a bunch of fuel to slow down, a course correction would be very small compared to that.  I wouldn't even be surprised if the cold gas thrusters could do it, though I certainly wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: no. You need to impart several hundred m/s to 30 tons of weight. For an ISS orbit, you need to change course by at least 50º, for example.

Answer (score 21):

Aside from the technical aspects, Africa is comprised of a couple of dozen different countries, all with their own rules and politics, but none of which would appreciate a botched booster landing in their urban centers. Even one incident like this would be enough to make sure no more flights happen.

Comment: Good point, but I would hope that they'd come to an arrangement with a willing partner and choose a location we'll away from any populated areas.

Comment: You only need the cooperation of a single country with a sufficiently large area of land. Maybe Morocco would be willing to rent one of its islands?

Comment: You'd still need to convince people your landing technology is safe and accurate, which is hard to do with any new technology. If the booster crashes into the sea 50 km off the intended landing site, nothing much happens. If the crashes into a city 50 km from the island you rented, ....

Comment: You would also need to get ITAR exemptions from the US gov't in order to 'export' the rocket. I suspect it would be an uphill battle.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: They managed to convince the US that they are able to land back at the launch site. I don’t know how far away the launch site is from cities, but I guess not extremely far?

Comment: @ChrisF: Not only is Africa composed of many different countries, few of those countries are politically stable.  So you build your landing facilities under one regime, launch your rocket, and then discover there's been a coup d'etat and the new rulers are holding it hostage...

Comment: @ChrisF, to put some hard numbers on jamesqf's point about political instability, only one of the 17 African countries that a low-inclination launch passes near has gone 30 years without a coup or civil war.

Comment: @Saiboogu that comment could become a fully formed answer of its own.  SpaceX does military work and therefore operates under some additional restrictions that a common commercial company doesn't.

Comment: @Michael Last time I looked, the USA didn't have any "willing partners" in Africa. And a failed landing near the straits of Gibraltar could potentially disrupt down shipping routes through the Suez canal and the Med much more effectively than Iran's attempts. You would probably have to clear a large area of commercial shipping at every landing in any case. The nice thing about the current sea landing area is that it isn't on any commercial shipping routes.

Comment: A couple dozen? Is 54 a couple dozen?

Comment: Eh, yes is it, in common speech. I certainly did not mean literally 2, as indicated by ‘dozen’ which is hardly a formal word too.

Comment: Nah, a couple is two and a dozen is twelve. In common speech, a couple dozen is approximately 24.

Comment: What an amazing on-topic discussion.

Answer (score 12):

We saw with the Falcon Heavy third flight (STP-2 mission) that the center core landing was attempted at 1240KM from launch, which is the farthest recovery attempt to date.

A consequence of the farther distance is that the speed of the core at separation is higher, which requires more fuel to slow down for the re-entry burn.

It appears they did not allocate sufficient fuel in the re-entry burn to slow down enough to survive.

This provides an excellent data point for SpaceX.

Thus to land in Africa means it would likely be moving much faster, and thus require more fuel to slow down to survive contact with the atmosphere.

The trade offs may not work out, compared to a landing closer to the launch site.

Comment: The center core failed to land because of a mechanical fault with the center engine's vectoring system. It had enough fuel.

Comment: From what Elon Musk said, that mechanical fault sounds like it was caused by excess heat - I guess that is the hazard of trying it faster than ever before.

Comment: @Adam apparently the TVC system firewall was breached due to excessive re-entry heating.

Comment: My interpretation of what he said was that they tried to push the limits on how how much re-entry heating it would be exposed to in order to conserve more fuel for the final landing burn. They could have slowed down the rocket earlier and higher in the atmosphere, but they chose not to because fuel was tight.

Answer (score 6):

As [Elon Musk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIvtiNpKEY0) explains Spacex is considered "Advanced Weapons Technology" by the America Gov, so limits employees to American citizens, I suspect this also limits where they are allow to land them.

Comment: The specific group of regulations you're thinking of is [ITAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Traffic_in_Arms_Regulations). This is a valid concern -- ITAR is quite broad in what it considers an "export" of defense-related technology.